# Replace with Regexp not working

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace a query string like this:

```
SELECT abc,def,ghi,jhk FROM table....
```

with

```
SELECT X FROM table....
```

this should be quite easy and i get the regexp replace to work as expected, but i cant get my expression right.
This is what i have:

```
rgx = new Regex("SELECT*.FROM");
data = rgx.Replace(data, "SELECT X FROM");
```

It also does not work in the online evaluator i tried, but i have no clue how it has to be then. And how do i get a modifier in there? I think it should be ungreedy.

I know that this whole thing might seem useless but this is exactly what i want and need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed up the `*` and `.`

Also you might want to add some spaces in there, otherwise the regex would also match `SELECTFOOBARFROM`.

Further more (assuming that C#'s Regexes support non-greediness) I'd make the wildcard non-greedy via a trailing `?`.
Right now your regex is greedy. As a result your current regex would change this:

```
SELECT Foo FROM Bar WHERE Baz IN (SELECT FooID FROM Bar WHERE Foo = 'Foo')
```

into this:

```
SELECT X FROM Bar WHERE Foo = 'Foo')
```

while the correct result would have been this:

```
SELECT X FROM Bar WHERE Baz IN (SELECT X FROM Bar WHERE Foo = 'Foo')
```

Ergo, go with this instead:

```
rgx = new Regex("SELECT .*? FROM");
```

Comment: yea was thinking that it should be ungreedy just did not know how to do it :) Thanks

Comment: +1for a very thorough analysis (and the right answer of course). :)

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
rgx = new Regex("SELECT.*FROM");
```

Note the order of the . and the *.

the * is basically a modifier for whatever character or group it follows so in yours you were matching 0 or more of the letter T instead of 0 or more of any character.